# Is circular dependency a bad practice?

Tags: database, entity-framework

Is there a way to avoid circular dependency in the following subsection of my database? 
Also, is it bad practice to have several circular dependencies?

I have received one error `may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths` but I can't simplify it so I removed the cascade constraints.

[image: Schema]

Update:
[Schema2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKOUM.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you shouldn't have a circular dependency here.

i think you are missing a table in between company and person (same structure as you did with the department and person)

1. when a person is deleted, then cascade to the department

   2. when a company is deleted, then cascade to the department
   3. when a department is deleted then cascade tot the person_department

that's it - no circles

Comment: Thank you. I uploaded `Schema 2` which contains other related tables. The issue is that Entity Framwork says that the circularity may be the FK in EmployeeDepartment and when I removed the cascade constaint for `delete`  it worked well.